# Extrema of a funcion of $x$ depending on $n$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have this function:

$$f(x)=\frac{x^{3}+3(\sqrt{n}-2)x^{2}-24\sqrt{n}x-2}{n^{2}}$$

I have to find the critical point of this funcion depending on $n\ge1\in \mathbb N$.

So I have computed the first derivative

$$f'(x)=\frac{3x^{2}+6(\sqrt{n}-2)x-24 \sqrt{n}}{n^{2}}$$

So the problem is, since in this case $n^{2}\ge1$ is always positive and $\neq 0$, studying:

$$3x^{2}+6(\sqrt{n}-2)x-24 \sqrt{n}=0$$

I've tried and tried to solve this equation without finding the correct answer. Could someone help me? Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have obtained a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then, as a standard method, we can apply the formula for the roots

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

to $$x^2+(2\sqrt n-4)x-8\sqrt n=0$$

and obtain

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}=\frac{-(2\sqrt n-4)\pm \sqrt{4n+16-16 \sqrt n + 32\sqrt n}}{2}=\frac{-(2\sqrt n-4)\pm (2\sqrt n+4)}{2}= 4, \quad-2\sqrt n$$

As an alternative, this is the way indicated by [Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2672381/505767), use that

$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=x^2-(x_1+x_2)x+x_1x_2=0$$

and thus

- $x_1+x_2=-2\sqrt n+4$
- $x_1x_2=-8\sqrt n$

and solve from here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was wondering why you have putted 
$$-4ac=32n$$
Instead of:
$$-4ac=-(-4*8*\sqrt{n})=32\sqrt{n}$$
Since $$c-8\sqrt{n}$$
Thank you very much. :).

Comment: just a typo, thanks I fix!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like
$$x^2+(2\sqrt n-4)x-8\sqrt n=0$$
which factors as
$$(x-4)(x+2\sqrt n)=0$$
etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The answer is correct. I'm interested on the method you've used to get that factors. Could you explain me it? Thank you so much. :).

Comment: Just inspection. I presume this was an example constructed to have a simple solution...

Comment: Yes, I think the same thing about the simple solutions. By the way, my difficult is to see that quickly and by inspection. Thank you :).